# Identify if an specific time is between a time range defined by two time fields

Tags: php, time

I have this variable containing a time:

```
$actualTime="22:00:00";
```

And a table `(turn_conf)` with scholar classes times, each one contaning 3 couples of time fields (6 time fields in total), indicating the time to start and finish each of the 3 blocks that every class can have (`tu_mon_1_s/tu_mon_1_e , tu_mon_2_s/tu_mon_2_e , tu_mon_3_s/tu_mon_3_e`).

As you see, can also be NULL for classes with only one or two blocks:

[image: Table extract]

I am looking for the most efficient way to check which element (tu_id) has a couple of blocks containig time given by `$actualTime`

Examples:

if  `$actualTime` stores "16:50:00", the Query must select tu_id **225**, because "16:50:00" is a time between `tu_mon_3_s` ("16:40:00) and `tu_mon_3_e` ("19:30:00).

if  `$actualTime` stores "13:30:00", the Query must select tu_id **253**, because "13:30:00" is a time between `tu_mon_1_s` ("11:00:00) and `tu_mon_1_e` ("14:00:00).

Comment: Please, post your current approach

Comment: So can you not write a query using `BETWEEN`?

Comment: @AlmaDo, as I am new to time fields, theres nothing I have done by the moment giving result. Sorry about that...

Comment: @kingkero is BETWEEN valid for time fields?

Comment: @AlmaDo because "just try" would result on, firstly, managing a type of data I am not experienced on, with the result of a lot of time loss and mostly sure a solution unefficient and improvable. With some help/clues/advices/mentions I would be able to invest and solve this by the correct way, trying with the correct methods. This is what this forum is suposed to and why I ask. I have investigated by myself the last hour and did not even get to the point that BETWEEN could be the best solution for this. NOW I am about to try, but based on an idea of people more experienced than me.

Comment: @Biomehanika "_managing a type of data I am not experienced on_" => you'll only get more experienced if you manage it more ;) When researching programming related topics, you usually don't lose time but use it for other things than the current problem - getting to know SQL better eg (which is imo not wasted time). Also generally there isn't a "correct way" to solve it, there may be nice looking, fast ones, but all that get the job done can be considered "correct". I would suggest that first you get it working and then think about performance (maybe better ask on codereview or dba than here)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. About the "correct way", its not just the nice look of the code, it is also the most effective way to solve it. I know almost any PHP problem has more than 3 solutions to get the same place, but the more efficient the solution is, the lighter and faster the system will run. And unexperienced and unaviced experiments with unknown types of data always result on hard and innecesary code, that's what I try to avoid. I'll keep in mind ur words.

Answer (score 1):

```
"SELECT tu_id FROM turn_conf WHERE 
(tu_mon_1_s >= " . $actualTime . " AND tu_mon_1_e <= " . $actualTime . ") OR
(tu_mon_2_s >= " . $actualTime . " AND tu_mon_2_e <= " . $actualTime . ") OR
(tu_mon_3_s >= " . $actualTime . " AND tu_mon_3_e <= " . $actualTime . ")"
```

Not tested out, but tell me if it worked.

Comment: I was thinking about using first CAST to set the string contained on $actualTime to TIME data, and then use BETWEEN. In case got no results with this, I'll try your way (I think also using CAST). I'll keep u informed, thank you for your attention.